# Find maximum range from other ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table described as

```
create table range (
    x int not null,
    y int not null,
    check (x < y)
);
```

Table is filled with ranges like this

```
insert into range(x,y) values (1,5);
insert into range(x,y) values (2,6);
insert into range(x,y) values (2,3);
insert into range(x,y) values (4,6);
insert into range(x,y) values (2,6);

insert into range(x,y) values (9,10);
insert into range(x,y) values (8,11);
insert into range(x,y) values (7,9);

insert into range(x,y) values (12,15);
```

I would like to query table with some select, which returns maximum continuous ranges.

```
select ????? from range
x , y
--------------
1 , 6
7 , 11
12, 15
```

Do I need recursion or window functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  The idea is to find where each group begins and then use a cumulative sum to define the groups ("islands").  Then an aggregation:

```
select min(x) as x, max(y) as y
from (select r.*,
            sum(isstart) over (order by x range between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp
      from (select r.*,
                   (not exists (select 1
                                from range r2
                                where r2.x < r.x and r2.y >= r.x
                               )
                   )::int as isstart
            from range r
           ) r
     ) r
group by grp
order by min(x);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fdb309/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note:  The `range between` should handle the situation where multiple ranges start on the same date and start a period of interest.